# use sed to search and replace patterns via regular expressions

Tags: regex, sed

trying to replace within a file everything including password up to the space.

```
password=xx%40%25PKz3L2jTa HTTP
```

tried the following sed command, using regular expression from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

```
 sed 's/password=(.)+/ /g' $file
```

and

```
 sed 's/password=[^ ]+/ /g' $file
```

none of the above works. why?

Comment: You have to escape +.  Try this: sed 's/password=[^ ]\+/ /g' $file

Comment: You can use `sed -E` to enable extended mode, which support +.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the `-r` argument:

```
sed -r 's/password=[^ ]+/ /g' $file
```

Comment: This relies on GNU `sed` (the `-r` option is not standard).  Using classic (POSIX) `sed`, you'd write a trivial variant: `sed 's/password=[^ ][^ ]*/ /g' $file`.

Comment: Thanks for that. It always worked for me, so I forgot it's not standard.

Answer (score 0):

The standard `sed` does not understand "extended" regular expression, such as '+'.  Two alternatives for you:

Enable extended regular expressions with

```
sed -E 's/password=[^ ]+/ /g' $file
```

or use standard regular expressions

```
sed 's/password=[^ ]*/ /g' $file
```

I prefer the second one because it is more portable and, unlike the first one, it will work with an empty password field.